# Multiple Aggregate Functions based on Multiple Columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am working with a Pandas df in Python.  I have the following input df:

```
Color   Shape   Value
Blue    Square  5
Red     Square  2
Green   Square  7
Blue    Circle  9
Blue    Square  2
Green   Circle  6
Red     Circle  2
Blue    Square  5
Blue    Circle  1
```

I would like the following output:

```
Color   Shape   Count   Sum
Blue    Square  3       12
Red     Square  1       2
Green   Square  1       7
Blue    Circle  2       10
Green   Circle  1       6
Red     Circle  1       2
```

Looking for something like pivot_table() but do not want the hierarchical index.

Comment: `df.groupby(['Color', 'Shape']).agg(['count', 'sum']).Value.reset_index()`?

Comment: Resetting the index works.  Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I am having is associated with indexing more than pivot tables.  To remove the multiple index a simple:

```
df.reset_index()
```

does the trick just fine.